# Pipe with ls command

Tags: pipe, ls, links

When I want to know if a command is a link or not, I do like following.

```
$ which locate
/usr/bin/locate
$ ls -l /usr/bin/locate
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24  5月  3  2012 /usr/bin/locate -> /etc/alternatives/locate
```

Is is possible to write by using pipe one line?
I tried `which locate | ls -l`. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xargs to forward the results of one command to another...

> which locate | xargs ls -al

Comment: Thanks! I thought xargs is used only when argument is too long.

Comment: Sure! It's got many handy uses. You're only forwarding one argument to it at a time here, but you can control how multiple arguments are passed to the target command. By default multiple arguments would be interpreted as "ls -al arg1 arg2 arg3" but adding the flag -n1 limits it to one argument resulting in  "ls -al arg1; ls -al arg2;..."  Use the -t flag to experiment and see the output of the commands xargs generates.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
ls -l `which locate`
```

Also, (at least on linux), take a look at:

```
namei `which locate`
```

Comment: I didn't know namei command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`readlink` will print the link target, or nothing (and return false) if its subject isn't a link.

```
which locate | xargs readlink
```

Comment: I always used `ls -l` to find link source. Thanks for your info!